# Get selected values in a dual listbox PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to output the selected values from the right hand listbox. However I am not successful in getting the values of selected values. The error returns from the submit function of js. Can anyone tell me why does it return:

```
An object doesn't support this property
```

in the submit function? How can i get the values.. will i use ajax or just returned value in PHP?

```
 <form name="frmListSubmit" method="post" id="myform" onsubmit="return submit()">

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="tblMain" class="edit">
    <tr valign="top">
       <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
       <td>
        <SELECT id="s" size="10" name="source" multiple>
        <?php 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getEmployeeList))
        {
        ?>
            <option name="list" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
       <?php 
        }
       ?>

      </td>
      </SELECT>

      <td valign="center">
          <a href="#" onclick="listbox_moveacross('s', 'd')" style="color:#FFF">&gt;&gt;</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="listbox_moveacross('d', 's')" style="color:#FFF">&lt;&lt;</a>
      </td>
      <td>
      <SELECT id="d" size="10" name="destination" multiple>
          <option name="list" value="">&nbsp;</option>
      </SELECT>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
     </td>
       </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

and here is the javascript code:

```
function listbox_moveacross(sourceID,destID)
{
var src=document.getElementById(sourceID);
var dest=document.getElementById(destID);
for(var count=0;count<src.options.length;count++)
{
    if(src.options[count].selected==true)
    {
        var option=src.options[count];
        var newOption=document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value=option.value;
        newOption.text=option.text;
        newOption.selected=true;
        try
        {
            dest.add(newOption,null);src.remove(count,null);
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            dest.add(newOption);src.remove(count);
        }

        count--;
        }
    }
}

function listbox_selectall(listID,isSelect)
{
var listbox=document.getElementById(listID);
for(var count=0;count<listbox.options.length;count++)
{
    istbox.options[count].selected=isSelect;
}
}

function submit() 
{
    listbox_selectall('d', true);
    return true;
 }
```

I have something like this in PHP and it returns only one ID after submission.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $_POST['destination'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the weird code:

```
function listbox_selectall(listID,isSelect)
{
    var listbox=document.getElementById(listID);
    for(var count=0;count<listbox.options.length;count++)
    {
        istbox.options[count].selected=isSelect;//<-- ?
    }
}
```

Maybe, you wanted to say:

```
listbox.options[count].selected=isSelect;
```

You said, that only 1 value from "destination" is submitted to PHP. To allow multiple values to be submitted, add [] to the names of the `<select>-s`:

```
<SELECT id="s" size="10" name="source[]" multiple>

<SELECT id="d" size="10" name="destination[]" multiple>
```

Also, there is no need to use `name` attribute for options. You don't use it anywhere.

Comment: sorry for the typo, i already changed but after submitting it doesn't return value.

Comment: @rmm04 Can you var_dump($_REQUEST); in the beginning of php code? So we could see, if anything is submitted at all?

Comment: @rmm04 You are giving me incorrect HTML code. There is no "id" input in the HTML in your question, while in var_dump result there is id. Plus in var_dump "destination" value is "A011479", while in HTML it has only 1 empty value. Please, edit your question and show the actual code, you are using. Plus I still don't understand, what doesn't work: javascript or the data is not sent to php script from the form?

Comment: These are the values returned by $_REQUEST after submitting the form: ["destination"]=> string(7) "A011479" ["submit"]=> string(6) "submit" other values beside this are URL values, these are the actual codes i'm using. i'm trying to figure out why it only returns one id after submitting. I want to return all id's i selected from the left listbox.